# Confidence interval for the absolute value of the mean

Tags: statistics, confidence-interval

I wondered if, given a confidence interval for the mean M, like

```
M included in [-a, b], with confidence 95% with a>0, b>0
```

it is correct to deduce that the absolute value of the mean:

`|M| = | [(1/N) * sum(x-M)] |`

is comprised between `[0, max(a,b)]`, with same confidence ?
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Disclaimer: I’m not a statistician, but I teach some statistics.

Good question!

This may be your question: Given a population of values for some quantitative variable $x$ and a fixed sample size $N$, suppose that the interval* $[-a,b]$ (where $-a<0<b$) captures exactly 95% of the distribution of sample means of size $N$ from the population. Then you want to know if is it the case that the interval $[0,\max(a,b)]$ captures 95% of the distribution of absolute values of sample means $\bar x$ of size $N$ from the same population.

The answer is no, if you mean “captures *exactly* 95%,” but yes if you want to know whether $[0,\max(a,b)]$ captures *at least* 95% of the distribution of absolute values of sample means of size $N$.

First of all, the phrase “the 95% confidence interval” is potentially imprecise, because it’s possible to choose more than one interval that contains 95% of the sample means. Let’s assume a conventional CI that also the property that the 5% of sample means that fall outside the CI are equally split between the two “outsides” of the CI. That assumption makes the definition of the CI unambiguous.***

If $[-a,b]$ is the “balanced CI” for the population, 2.5% of the sample means are less than $-a$, 95% of them are between $-a$ and $b$, and 2.5% of them are greater than $b$.

Suppose for the moment that $a<b$, so that $\max(a,b)=b$. You want to know if $[0,b]$ contains 95% of the absolute values of the sample means. It contains at least that many. All of the sample means that lie between $-a$ and $b$ (which is 95% of them) have absolute values between $0$ and $b$. All of the sample means that lie to the right of $b$ (which is 2.5% of them) have absolute values that are *not* in $[0,b]$.

However, the remaining 2.5% of sample means (those less than $-a$) may or may not have absolute values in $[0,b]$. There isn’t enough information to determine how many do. Those sample means that are less than $-a$ but **not** less than $-b$ do have absolute values in $[0,b]$. Those that are less than $-a$ and also less than $-b$ do not. Since exactly 2.5% of the sample means are less than $-a$, the interval $[0,b]$ contains between 95% and 97.5% of all absolute values of sample means.**

*Note that in practice, a CI is computed from a single sample and straddles the sample mean in such a way that under reasonable assumptions, one can assume with 95% confidence that it contains the actual (unknown) population mean. My description is for an interval that, given a known distribution, straddles the population mean in such a way that 95% of all possible sample means lie within the interval.

**If the distribution of sample means is known, an exact answer can be found; for normally distributed sample means, as an example, it will depend on the normalized difference between $|a|$ and $|b|$.

***If we don’t make the CI balanced in this way, the interval $[0,b]$ is still known to capture between 95% and 100% of the absolute values, but we don’t know that it captures at most 97.5%.

Comment: Thanks for answering, I don't think you understood my question because it is maybe too simple, so I tried to make it more clear. Comparing to your answer, the mean of your {-1, 1} data is equal to 0. So the absolute value of this mean is also 0 and I just would like to generalize by deducing the CI for the absolute value of the mean from its CI without absolute value, which is two sided so for me its trivial but I don't want to neglect any theoretical issue.

Comment: Sorry, I misunderstood and thought you were asking about the CI for the mean of the absolute value.

Comment: Thank you! Is it possible then to generalize: provided any CI for the mean M e.g [-a, b], [a, b], [-b, -a], applying the correct "absolute transform" for inequalities on the CI  -> |CI|, provides always a CI for |M| with at least 95% of confidence? For example (inspired from your answer): I would say that, knowing a CI contains M, the correct transformed |CI| always contains |M| by definition, but if the CI doesn't contain M, the transformed |CI| may or may not contain |M|. Therefore, I can say that |CI| will always represent a CI with at least 95% of confidence for |M| ?

Comment: I think your last statement is correct; in the cases where $a$ and $b$ are both on the same side of zero, the $CI$ for the mean and the absolute mean are the same or reflected about $0$, and otherwise, the $|CI|$ has at least as high confidence for capturing $|M|$ as $CI$ does $M$. But as I noted, I’m not a real statistician, and if I’m missing some subtlety, let’s hope someone chimes in.